How can I implement fluid conversation with Nao?
My current project is to add conversational AI to the nao robot.
At the moment, I'm using naoqi's ALAudioRecorder and then downloading the wav file via ssh with paramiko to process it with speech to text and send it to gemini or llama3.
Here is the code
Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same result? It takes a few seconds and I'd like to optimise it so that the conversation is more natural.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
